# Get table row value with jQuery/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get table value names with the following code:

my table :

```
        function CreateBlockDeployTableRow(data) {
         return "<tr>" +
        "<td>" + data.EnvTypeName + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + data.AppTypeName + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + deleteBtn + "</td>" +
        "</tr>";
        }
```

my button:

```
        var deleteBtn = '<button class="btn btn-danger unblock-button btn-sm 
        glyphicon glyphicon-minus" type=button > </button> '
```

on click function:

```
      function UnblockRequestHandler()
        {
        $('.unblock-button').click(function () {
        sendUnblockDeploySubmitHandler();
        });
       }
```

and here I want to send my Environment and Application to server side and take the value of the rows in the table , but the code is not working and not taking anything:

```
       function sendUnblockDeploySubmitHandler() {
       var $row = jQuery(this).closest('tr');
       var $columns = $row.find('td');

        $columns.addClass('row-highlight');
        var values = "";

          jQuery.each($columns, function (i, item) {
           values = values + 'td' + (i + 1) + ':' + item.innerHTML + 
          '<br/>';
        alert(values);
         });
           console.log(values);
          }
```

html code :

```
       <div class="tbl-responsive">
      <table id="blockDeployTable" class="table table-hover 
       requestsblockDeployTable" style="font-size: 0.8em; margin-top: 120px; 
        text-align:center">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Environment</th>
            <th>Repo</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

Where am I wrong here I cannot understand?

Comment: Please include the corresponding HTML, so we can use it to troubleshoot your code.

Comment: Sorry, I added it now.

Comment: Do you bind (or refresh) your click event after inserting all table elements into the DOM Tree ?

Comment: I don't think that it is necessary to refresh after I click delete. Currently I do not, the code that I provide is all the code I wrote until now.

Comment: var $row = jQuery(this).closest('tr'); what actully your $this has at this line. it matters

Comment: If you try to bind your "UnblockRequestHandler" callback before adding your elements in the DOM, your elements will never be triggered. I don't see in the code  where you call your function "UnblockRequestHandler".

Comment: UnblockRequestHandler is fired on click of the button: Also i call it in get all method which loads the page

Comment: What does the `alert()` and `console.log()` print out from your current code?

Comment: Now empty string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just pass the click event through to the `sendUnblockDeploySubmitHandler` function:

```
$('.unblock-button').click(function () {
  sendUnblockDeploySubmitHandler(event); // pass event to function
});

function sendUnblockDeploySubmitHandler(event) {
  var $row = $(event.target).closest('tr'); // event.target is the button
  var $columns = $row.find('td');

  $columns.addClass('row-highlight');
  var values = "";

  jQuery.each($columns, function (i, item) {
   values = values + 'td' + (i + 1) + ':' + item.innerHTML + '<br/>';
   alert(values);
  });

  console.log(values);
}
```

I've put together a jsbin to show this working:  https://jsbin.com/sosimudubi/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: You probably don't want to output the button itself in the each function so just do a check to see if `i < 2` before updating the `values` variable.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access `jQuery(this)` in the `sendUnblockDeploySubmitHandler()` method but the `this` handle does not refer to the `button` element. I would suggest you to directly pass the callback function when you bind the click event.

```
function UnblockRequestHandler() {
    $('.unblock-button').click(sendUnblockDeploySubmitHandler);
}
```

This way, you can access the corresponding `button` element using `jQuery(this)` in the `sendUnblockDeploySubmitHandler()`

Comment: Just want to make sure that you are NOT putting brackets after the method name that you are passing to click().

// No brackets () after sendUnblockDeploySubmitHandler
$('.unblock-button').click(sendUnblockDeploySubmitHandler);

Comment: Also make sure that you call the method UnblockRequestHandler() after the table is completely loaded with all the rows